# Kubuntu 16.04 Where is apps store? and How do I install packages?

Tags: package-management

I want to install apps from Apps Store like Ubuntu.
thou I after exploring Kubuntu i think there is no such application like store. So i will download it manually depending it's availability. Now .debs file should be easier to install and more user friendly than using traditional terminal. What app should i download/install for Installing packages like deb?
How to install it still newbie in the world of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

The "App Store" in Kubuntu is called "Muon Discover". You should look for this name.